# How to store variable and use it as a -Pattern from Get-Content?

Tags: windows, powershell

Trying to check if few software are installed, when I use this code, it works fine:

```
$Pattern = "Winr","adobe";$software = get-package | Select-Object Name; $array = @($software.name) | Set-Content C:\temp\installed.txt; $SEL = Select-String -Path C:\temp\installed.txt -Pattern $Pattern; if ($SEL -ne $null) {write-host Found => $SEL.Line} else {write-host Nothing Found}
```

This code works without issues, but when I try to get the variables from a text file, it is not working with this code:

```
$Pattern = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt; $software = get-package | Select-Object Name; $array = @($software.name) | Set-Content C:\temp\installed.txt; $SEL = Select-String -Path C:\temp\installed.txt -Pattern $Pattern; if ($SEL -ne $null) {write-host Found => $SEL.Line} else {write-host Nothing Found}
```

[image]

The text file contain the following text:

`"Winr","adobe"`

How to use the content of the text file as a `-Pattern` in `Select-String`

Any idea to solve this issue?
Regards

Comment: for ref. `if ($SEL -ne $null)` can be just `if ($SEL)`. you should also use `-SimpleMatch` in your `Select-String` statement since you're interested in matching literally.

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon

Thank you, -SimpleMatch is a very useful parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list.txt should look like:

```
winr
adobe
```

for pattern to be an array of strings:

```
$pattern = get-content list.txt
select-string -pattern $pattern -path installed.txt
```

Note that you can simply say:

```
get-package *winr*,*adobe*
```

or

```
$pattern = echo *winr*,
  *adobe*
get-package $pattern
```

Since get-package accepts a string array of names and you can use wildcards.  (Powershell 5.1 only for msi and programs providers.)